# dir_tree() to HTML/Table

Tags: r, directory, dropdown

I have a very large folder with many subfolders and hence a large number of files. I would like to create an HTML file with the folder structure with dropdown options for the different levels as well as a searchbar. I thought about `reactable` or a small `shiny` app, but maybe someone has an idea. My first problem is to get the structure from `fs::fs_tree` into a suitable format.

Consider the following folder structure:

```
fs::fs_tree()

├── folder1
├── folder2
│   └── readme.R
├── folder3
│   ├── subfolder1
│   │   ├── example.R
│   │   └── example2.R
│   └── subfolder2
│       └── plot.R
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**jsTreeR**](https://github.com/stla/jsTreeR) package.

You don't need a Shiny app since a "jsTree" is a HTML widget, and you can save it as a HTML file with `htmlwidgets::saveWidget`.

Here is the folder example of this package:

```r
library(jsTreeR)

# make the nodes list from a vector of file paths
makeNodes <- function(leaves){
  dfs <- lapply(strsplit(leaves, "/"), function(s){
    item <-
      Reduce(function(a,b) paste0(a,"/",b), s[-1], s[1], accumulate = TRUE)
    data.frame(
      item = item,
      parent = c("root", item[-length(item)]),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  })
  dat <- dfs[[1]]
  for(i in 2:length(dfs)){
    dat <- merge(dat, dfs[[i]], all = TRUE)
  }
  f <- function(parent){
    i <- match(parent, dat$item)
    item <- dat$item[i]
    children <- dat$item[dat$parent==item]
    label <- tail(strsplit(item, "/")[[1]], 1)
    if(length(children)){
      list(
        text = label,
        data = list(value = item),
        children = lapply(children, f)
      )
    }else{
      list(text = label, data = list(value = item))
    }
  }
  lapply(dat$item[dat$parent == "root"], f)
}

folder <-
  list.files(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), recursive = TRUE)

nodes <- makeNodes(folder)

jstree(nodes, search = TRUE)
```

[image]